# How can I setup an embedded ApacheDS in Junit5

Tags: ldap, junit5, apacheds

In the ApacheDS documentation about embedding an ApacheDS server in Junit test they only mentions example for Junit4 using

```java
@RunWith(FrameworkRunner.class)
```

or

```java
@ClassRule
public static CreateLdapServerRule serverRule = new CreateLdapServerRule();
```

But `RunWith` and `ClassRule` are not available in Junit5.

How can I run Junit5 tests with an embedded ApacheDS LdapServer ?

Answer (score 0):

Using apacheds-test-framework >= 2.0.0.AM27 you can use

```
@ExtendWith(ApacheDSTestExtension.class)
```